# Visual Studio Code files.exclude setting not working

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using Unity and trying to exclude .meta files from the file explorer sidebar.  I navigated to File->Preferences->User Settings (or Workspace settings, doesn't matter), and set the contents of the file to the following:

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite default and user settings.
{
        "files.exclude": {
        "**/.meta": true
    }
}
```

...and saved my changes.  Yet, when I click the Refresh icon or close/reopen my folder view, I am still seeing all the .meta files showing up in the left pane.  Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

My problem was basing my pattern off of the existing ones, which excluded specific file names rather than patterns.  I simply needed to add an asterisk before the file extension, i.e.

```
"**/*.meta"
```

instead of

```
"**/.meta"
```

Comment: Thank you for solving and sharing this solution!

Comment: @vargonian you can accept your own answer  in case you don't know :)

Answer (score 29):

Check this button if you're seeing excluded files in **search**.

[image: VSCode search settings]

The **cog button** needs to be **highlighted** in order for `files.exclude` to apply.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5):

It's also worth noting that, in the search sidebar, "files to exclude" and "files excluded through settings" behave differently.

In "files to exclude", it's sufficient to write `*.meta`, but in "files excluded through settings" (set in the user settings file) you must write `**/*.meta`.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this path:
C:>Users>UserName>AppData>Roaming>Code>User>settings.json
and remove line '**/.project':true