# VS Code search.exclude doesn't work

Tags: ide, visual-studio-code

I can't make `search.exclude` settings to work, so that it excludes `build` folder.

Here's screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Hm, interesting - I can reproduce that, but.. now always. Seems like it might be related to VSCode being opened before the `build` directory is created? Anyway, [#24677](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/24677) seems relevant.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This looks like this bug: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/31819 - `search.exclude` won't apply to open files.

Comment: This was it. Jesus Christ.

Comment: 5 year old issue, still frustrating developers

Answer (score 91):

Just in case this helps anyone else, here's a list of things that could be affecting whether your file/search exclusion settings are working as expected.

- Double-check whether you're using the right patterns; you can see what kinds of patterns VS Code supports [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_advanced-search-options). One [common problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33812100/visual-studio-code-files-exclude-setting-not-working) is to not add `*` before an extension you want to exclude, e.g. `**/.min.js` will exclude all files named ".min.js", while `**/*.min.js` will exclude all files *ending in* ".min.js".
- Make sure the "Use Exclude Settings and Ignore Files" gear is toggled on (it's next to the "files to exclude" field; if you don't see it, click the little "..." under the "Replace" field). Turning it on will exclude any patterns in your `search.exclude` settings **and** patterns defined in any .gitignore files. This only affects whether your exclusion settings will be applied to your search; any pattern you put into the "files to exclude" input field will always be applied.
  [image: screenshot showing the search tab open, the location of gear icon to "Use Exclude Settings and Ignore Files"]
- If you don't want to exclude .gitignore patterns, set `search.useIgnoreFiles` to false (it's true by default). If a pattern is excluded in some .gitignore file and `search.useIgnoreFiles` is true, even if you add that pattern to your `search.exclude` and set it to false, it will still be ignored ([see this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/40667)).
- Any patterns in `files.exclude` will [automatically be excluded from search results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971600/how-can-i-choose-folders-to-be-ignored-during-search), not just from the file explorer.
- All of the default patterns will be excluded even when you create your own `files.exclude` or `search.exclude` settings field. To override the default exclusion patterns, you must copy each default pattern into your user-defined settings and set them to false, e.g. `"search.exclude": {"**/node_modules": false, "**/bower_components": false}`.
- As noted by the accepted answer, any currently opened files will always be included in results, even if they're excluded in your settings.
- As of now, VS Code doesn't support [negated glob exclusions](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/869), so if your `search.exclude` has patterns like this `{"**/*": true, "**/myfolder": false}`, files in "myfolder" won't be included in your results. Instead, you must exhaustively list all folders you want excluded.
- Any settings in User Settings will be applied globally while Workspace Settings will only apply to the current workspace, so make sure you're placing your settings in the section you want.

If you're still having problems, you can see which folders VS Code is excluding by setting the log level to trace and reading the output when you perform a search ([see here for more instructions](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/43695)).

Comment: Wow it was the "Use Exclude Settings and Ignore Files" gear icon for me.  Not intuitive.

Comment: Is it possible to apply `"Use Exclude Settings and Ignore Files" ` option to `files.exclude` too? Seems its only available for `search.exclude` :(

Comment: What a wildly bad design (the hidden gear toggle) that apparently hasn't been fixed in 3 years.  Thanks for the nice summary.

Answer (score 1):

`**/build` did not work for me. Instead I use `build/**` and it works.

Comment: Is this a comment on one of the other answers? What are you referrng to?

Comment: This is an answer on how to fix the problem. OP wants to ignore `build` folder and I can see they used `**/build` but they need to use `build/**`. I will rename my answer `dist` -> `build` so it's more clear.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that **search.useRipgrep** ignores the exclude settings. For me the exclude started working when I disabled search.useRipgrep.

My Environment: Windows 10; VSC installed in User Directory (as recommended per last Update).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't managed to get VSCode to ignore a folder with `search.exclude`, regardless of the position of `**` and so on.

However, what worked for me is creating an `.ignore` file and then enabling `"search.useParentIgnoreFiles": true` in the workspace settings.

My folder layout:

```
root/
  ...
  text/
    .ignore
    code_ner
      ...
      output/         <- want to ignore
      envs/           <- want to ignore
```

Contents of the `.ignore` file:

```
envs/
code_ner/output
```