# Visual Studio Code "find..." not searching gitignored files

Tags: visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code appears to not be searching my entire project.  For example, if I do `Go to file...` and search for "http.php" -- as in the screenshot below -- the `http.php` file is not returned, even though that file is in the workspace.  If I open the http.php file in the editor and then search for it, it is shown correctly in the search results.

[image]

The same thing occurs if I do a `Find in files...` for the text "class Http".  Some files are returned, but not the `http.php` file even though that file does have `class Http...` in it.  As above, if I open the `http.php` file in the editor, then `Find in files...` does correctly return that file.

As far as I can tell, Visual Studio Code is not searching folders/files that are in my `.gitignore` unless I specifically open those files in the editor.  Is there any way to have Visual Studio Code performs searches in those gitignored files (without removing those files from `.gitignore`)?

Comment: Set the setting `"search.useIgnoreFiles": false`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45895070/vs-code-search-exclude-doesnt-work

Comment: Thank you.  I felt a little silly making this post because I figured someone else had already answered it, but I couldn't find the answer.